# VBA Access User-Defined Type not Defined when Running my AutoExec Macro

Tags: ms-access, vba, user-defined-types, autoexec

I am trying to test out my code that I have written, and when I go to run my AutoExec macro, I get the error

> "User-defined type not Defined"

on the following line of code:

```
Public Sub WFR_Style(xlBook As Excel.Workbook)
```

I have the following references set up under my Tools->References:

- Microsoft Access 16.0 Object Library
- OLE Automation
- Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library
- Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine object library
- Visual Basic for Applications

Am I missing any?

Comment: Arent you missing an excel object model reference?

Comment: How are you specifying the xlbook parameter?

Comment: As Doug said, go into Tools>References and Add Excel

Comment: I am specifying the xlBook as an Object

Comment: If you don't want to set the reference to Excel (why? if you have Outlook and Office already?), you'll need to do `Public Sub WFR_Style(xlBook As Object)`